# Synchronized methods across different devices (IOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

What is the best way (if at all possible) to synchronize execution of methods on different devices? For example, let's say there are two people standing next to each other, each with their own device, and i want their phones to flash/alternate a background color of a view at the same time, in what would appear to be a synchronized manner. My original approach was for there to be a set date (in the future), on which each device would fire the methods. I've done this using performSelector withDelay method, as well as the NSTimer fireWithDate init method, but when trying on simulator and my actual device, the timing is off. I assume this is bc the hardware of the computer is much stronger and thus processes the method with more accuracy, but is this the right approach, and should it in theory work on actual devices (will test soon)..?

Thanks!

Comment: What will be trigger that starts the flashing?

Comment: it can be anything, but for example they could both just tap a button.

Comment: If that is the case, I guess you could do as follows: start apps on both devices, make apps do a socket connection, transfer timestamps, set a timer accordingly and run the method

Comment: why would i need to transfer timestamps? I believe that all phones are synchronized on the exact same time when they have cell service.

Comment: timestamps, when you need to do the flashing sometime in future

Comment: Yes, they currently both get this timestamp from a server, it is in essence a future date which they both retrieve (same date for both of them).